# How did non-US citizens with old birth certificate for minor US child renew passports after 2011?

Tags: usa, passport, social-security, birth-certificate

In April 2011, only birth certificates with both parents name were accepted for passport applications. How would non-US citizens living out of US, renew passport of the minor US child, if they did not meet sudden change in requirement?

Comment: Why doesn't the child's birth certificate name both parents?  That is fairly unusual.

Comment: @phoog I know that in my state a short certificate that did not list the parent's names cost less than a longer certificate, which is more complete. I have one of each.